# Can I say Random Forest fits better than Linear Regression in my case?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, random-forest

I have a regression problem and I tried both Regular Regression and Random Forest.
Here is my code

```
 from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()

clf.fit(X, y)

print('Raw Coefficients: \n', clf.coef_)
print('Score: \n',clf.score(X, y));


# Now we normalise the data
scalerX = StandardScaler().fit(X)
scalery = StandardScaler().fit(y) # Have to reshape to avoid warnings

normed_X = scalerX.transform(X)
normed_y = scalery.transform(y) # Have to reshape to avoid warnings
scaledclf = linear_model.LinearRegression()

scaledclf.fit(normed_X, y)
print('Scaled Coefficients: \n', scaledclf.coef_)
print('Score: \n', scaledclf.score(normed_X, y));

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regr = RandomForestRegressor()
regr.fit(X, y)
print('Feature importance: \n')
print(regr.feature_importances_)
print('Forest Score: \n', regr.score(X, y));
```

From the output, I can see that the R2 score of linear regression (either scaled or raw) are 0.27. But random forest gives me 0.9. (according to document, 1 is the most accurate).

In this case, can I say my data is better suited in a Random forest Regressor other than linear Regressor? (which I think implies my data is not linear, and better fitted by a non linear model)

```
Raw Coefficients:
 [[-2.46128236  6.50261042  4.23066487  0.16846074 -0.42161622  0.52332136]
 [ 8.7998738  19.23413227 58.76010742  1.02298612 -3.28209941 -2.99637104]]
Score:
 0.27018867990736034
Scaled Coefficients:
 [[-0.83667512  2.32189634  2.03873375  1.47020538 -1.27457093  0.38564757]
 [ 2.99138188  6.86795895 28.31616729  8.92789452 -9.92198189 -2.20809484]]
Score:
 0.27018867990736056
Feature importance:

[0.04388598 0.0329269  0.18755359 0.35849597 0.31578241 0.06135516]
Forest Score:
 0.9003045525566503
```

Comment: Hard to tell just with R^2 score, you have to test each model on a test set to determine if any has overfit.

Comment: Have you tried your two models with test data to see which performs best? The R^2 is only an indicator and shouldn't be treated as gospel. The proof of the pudding is in the eating.

Comment: @user2974951, Hi, how can I plot RandomForestRegressor to see if overfit happens? Do you have any examples? thanks

Comment: You don't plot your model to establish if it's overfit, you really need a test set, or at least a Cross-Validation procedure

Comment: Would you please add a scatterplot of the raw data to the question?

Comment: @James Phillips Hi, my input has multiple data features, so does my output Y. Will scatter show anything in this case?

Comment: I do not know yet.